# TypeError: Must be String, not list

Tags: python, list, formatting, output

I'm sure this is already posted somewhere between StackOverflow and Google but I am unable to find the solution because I don't know the exact terms to search.

I'm going to try to be as specific as possible.  I have a bunch of zip files with with reports inside of them with names like Process123456789results.csv.  I need to rename the CSV file to the name of its parent ZIP folder.

So for ease of understanding I need to turn this:

- IntendedName.zip --> Process123456789results.csv

Into this:

- IntendedName.csv

To do that I am using ZipFile, my script looks a bit like this (very inexperienced programmer here so all criticism is welcome):

```
Extracted = []
x = 0

for attachment in zip:
with zipfile.ZipFile("IntendedName.zip", "r") as z:
    z.extractall()
    Extracted = [z.namelist()]
    os.rename(Extracted[x], "IntendedName.csv")
os.remove("IntendedName.zip")
x +=1
```

Ideally the end result will be:

1. Extract the CSV
2. Rename the CSV to the ZIP files name.
3. Cleanup the zip file leaving only the renamed CSV.

My issues:

1. Running my code I am given the following error **must be string, not list**.  I've tried approaching this from a couple different angles but can't quite get around this.  I know it's not the same thing but I was reading about "typecasting" in C.  Is there something similar I can do here?  I was going to get a list of all names and export it to a text file and use that..But that feels like a dirty way to tackle this.
2. I don't know if this will be an issue but using a debugger I can see the value of "Extracted" ends up looking like this: **[u'Process123456789results.csv']** when it's called from *z.namelist()* which *I think* (unconfirmed) will break the the script after number 1 is fixed because when I try to rename the file it will be unable to find a file by the bold name above instead of just "Process123456789results.csv".  Is it possible to modify a list by just deleting the extraneous characters?  This could just be me over thinking this.  I don't even know if this is a problem because I can't get passed the issue stated above.

I apologize if I have been unclear about something.  I'll do my best to answer any questions.  I can post the entire code I am working on if it will help.  It's not exactly pretty, though.

**SOLUTION:**

After getting some direction I was able to figure out how to tackle this.  The issue I was talking about in number 2 above never became an issue.  Number 1 was resolved by some very helpful individuals below.

The "index out of error" issue I mentioned in the comments to Shank was resolved with the following code:

```
Extracted = []
x = 0

for attachment in zip:
with zipfile.ZipFile("IntendedName.zip", "r") as z:
    z.extractall()
    Extracted.extend(z.namelist())
    os.rename(Extracted[x], "IntendedName.csv")
os.remove("IntendedName.zip")
x +=1
```

Edit: Removed redundant parenthesis.
Edit again: Added a completed solution.  Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: must be str, not list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612799/typeerror-must-be-str-not-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `os.rename(Extracted[x], "IntendedName.csv")`, `Extracted[0]` seems to be pointing to a list of names. If you want to iterate through the namelist, just have your assignment be `Extracted = z.namelist()`. When you do `Extracted = [z.namelist()]`, it wraps a list within a list, so when you access the 0 index element to pass it into `os.rename`, you're actually passing in a list as the first parameter, not a string as it expects.

Comment: Thank you for this.  However, I initially tried getting rid of the brackets and in doing so noticed that I was getting an "index out of range" error.  The debugger showed me that instead of adding a new value to the extracted list it was actually overwriting the value for "Extracted".  The result was a single file being renamed correctly and then an indexing error on the second iteration.

Comment: More poking around solved this for me.  After looking at your answer I started looking more into the different options that lists have to offer.  I tried using ".append" but could not get it to work.  Then I tried ".extend" and it worked successfully.  I will update my main post with working code for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is this line:

```
Extracted = [z.namelist()]
```

I'm guessing `namelist()` already returns a list, so you're putting a list inside a list. I think you meant this instead:

```
Extracted = z.namelist()
```