# TypeError: must be str, not list

Tags: python, csv, tf-idf

the problem is output result is not save in csv file.
I'm using this code to weight-age the words positive and negative.I want to save in the csv file.Firstly, read the csv file ,apply tf-idf and output display on shell,but error disply when result write in csv file.

```
for i, blob in enumerate(bloblist):
    print("Top words in document {}".format(i + 1))
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
    sorted_words = sorted(scores.items(), reverse=True)
    print(sorted_words)
    final = open("tfidf.csv", "w").write(sorted_words)
    print(final)
    print("done")
```

The error is:

```
   Top words in document 1
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\webcrawler-Final.py", line 38, in <module>
   final = open("tfidf.csv", "w").write(sorted_words)
   TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: try  `final = open("tfidf.csv", "w").write(str(sorted_words))`

Comment: use `open("tfidf.csv", "w").write(" ".join(sorted_words))`, This would concatenate your list items and return a string, `" ".join(['1', '2', '3'])` would return `1 2 3` but if you want to write in the format of list then try @Borja method.

Comment: @Borja it works thanks but i want not to save paranthesis with data. e.g           the ('Pakistan', 0.0), i want data save in this style i-e Pakistan ,0.0

Comment: Have you tried @ZdaR solution?

Comment: Oh @Anaya , `Pakistan` interesting ;) , you may try `", ".join(('India', 10.0))` which returns `India ,10.0` and embedding this in your code: `open("tfidf.csv", "w").write(", ".join(sorted_words))`

Comment: yes ,but the error occur is: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Comment: @ZdaR it does not work. The error is same that ,I mentioned above. And this is news data.

Comment: Please, write the content of `sorted_words`

Comment: I have posted an answer, comment on it which thing is not working by your side.

Comment: It would be nice if you post the contents of `sorted_words` in the question.

Comment: Ah I got it , so your `sorted_words` looks something like: `(("Pakistan", 0.0), ("Arab", 1.0), ("USA:, 2.0))` @Anaya ?

Comment: yes this is the output of this code

Comment: And this is exactly same save in the file.

Comment: @ZdaR only i want this output "Pakistan ,0.0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79496/discussion-between-zdar-and-anaya).

Comment: the output is this. ('‘Pakistan', 0.0), ('yuan', 0.0019977921698040337), ('yet', -0.0015496079952375674), ('widen', -0.0015496079952375674), ('why', 0.0019977921698040337)

Comment: @Borja I want the entire list

Comment: come to chatroom, SO won't allow so much comments, I would try to solve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try to this.

```
sorted_words = ''.join(sorted(scores.items(), reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you dont specify in your post, I dont know which is the separator between values of the tuple, so I added a `'\n'`. You can change that to `' '` or whatever you want.

`final = open("tfidf.csv", "w").write('\n'.join('%s, %s' % x for x in sorted_words))`

Comment: there is some problem to save data in file. there are three documents and only the last document is save in the file.

Comment: file = open("example1.txt" , 'r').read()
file2 = open("heading.txt", 'r').read()
file3 = open("example2.txt",'r').read()
document = tb(file)
document2 = tb(file2)
document3 = tb(file3)

bloblist = [document,document2,document3]                                               after these lines of code , remaining code is mentioned above.