# TypeError: must be str, not list in Python 3 when calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a function to count a letter for example letter e. My function looks something similar to this:

```
def count_letter(sentence, accents, case):

    lower_case_e = ['e']
    upper_case_E = ['E']
    accent_lower_case = ['é', 'ê', 'è']
    accent_upper_case = ['É', 'Ê', 'È']

    for character in sentence:#If statement for optional argument where ignore_accents == True and ignore_case == False.
        #This loop will count lower case and upper case e as differente letters but will treat accented characters the same.

        if accents == True and case == False:
            lower_case_count = sentence.count(lower_case_e)
            accent_lower_case_count = sentence.count(accent_lower_case)
            upper_case_count = sentence.count(upper_case_E)
            accent_upper_case_count = sentence.count(accent_upper_case)

            total_e_count = lower_case_count + accent_lower_case_count
            total_E_count = upper_case_count + accent_upper_case_count

            return {'Total number of lower case e in sentence ignoring accents':total_e_count, 'Total number of upper case E in sentence ignoring accents':total_E_count }
```

The point of this function is to count the letter e and depending if it is lower or upper case or if it has accents, to sum the letters together. I created a text file called sentence.txt and it looks like this:

```
Testing if function can count letter e or E.
```

I have read the file using the following code:

```
# Reading the data from sentence.txt as a string
with open('sentence.txt', 'r') as Sentence_file:
    Sentence_string=Sentence_file.read().replace('\n', '')
```

And after reading the file I try to call the function in the following way:

```
count_letter(sentence, True, False)
```

However when I try to run this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Anyone have any idea of what could be going wrong? Could the error be in the way I am reading my txt.file? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Full error trace looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b171590ddd67> in <module>()
     29 with open('Test_Sentence1.txt', 'r') as Sentence1_file:
     30     Sentence1=Sentence1_file.read().replace('\n', '')
---> 31 count_letter_e(Sentence1, True, False)
     32 

<ipython-input-2-b171590ddd67> in count_letter_e(sentence, accents, case)
     18         if accents == True and case == False:#If statement for optional argument where ignore_accents == True and ignore_case == False.
     19             #This loop will count lower case and upper case e as differente letters but will treat accented characters the same.
---> 20             lower_case_count = sentence.count(lower_case_e)#counting lower case e with no accent from the sentence
     21             accent_lower_case_count = sentence.count(accent_lower_case)#counting lower case e with accents from the sentence
     22             upper_case_count = sentence.count(upper_case_E)#counting upper case E with no accent from the sentence

TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: What's the exact error with trace?

Comment: Is this a homework problem that you are looking for help on?

Comment: That function is definitely wrong. Either you will uselessly go through your `for` loop as many times as there are characters in your sentence and eventually return `None` or you will only do one iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: @pcurry if it's homework, they've put sufficient effort in I'd guess. It's not _forbidden_ to ask homework questions.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I have updated the full error trace

Comment: @adda.fuentes Did you check the docs for the `count` method? It likely takes a string, not a list. There's only 1 function call on the line the trace points to. That would have been a good place to start debugging this yourself.

Comment: The substring parameter has to be of type `str`. You've set it to a list, thus it returns that `TypeError`. `accent_lower_case` is a list. You need to iterate through the list before calling `count()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: must be str, not list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612799/typeerror-must-be-str-not-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "**count()**" function only accepts a string as input. For example:

```
lower_case_count = 0
for lower_case_e_char in lower_case_e:
    lower_case_count += sentence.count(lower_case_e_char)
print(lower_case_count)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the line indicated in the stack trace, you are calling the `.count()` method and passing in the variable `lower_case_e` which has a value of `['e']`. The `.count()` method expects a string to count, not multiple values. Example:

```
>>> testing = 'aba'
>>> testing.count('a')
2
>>> testing.count(['a'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

So, for the values you want to count that have multiple characters (such as accent lower case), you will need to to loop through and add up the value of `count()` for each string method, not the entire list at one time.

Answer (score 0):

You `sentence.count()` expect a [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count), not a list. Change your lower case, upper case etc to strings. For example, `lower_case_e = 'e'` instead of `['e']`. It should resolve your error. For the rest, you need to improve your function in many other ways.

you can try something like:

```
lower_case_e = 'e' 
lower_case_count = sentence.count(lower_case_e)   
accent_lower_case_count = [sentence.count(item) for item in accent_lower_case] 
total_e_count = lower_case_count + sum(accent_lower_case_count)
```

You can see this from error message. Look at line 31 and then 20, you can see that something is wrong with sentence.count(). Then inspect the error message which tells you that something went wrong because a list was seen by the function while it was expecting a string. 
These pointers should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the length of the string you're processing, it might save you substantial time to run through the string ONCE, counting your characters as you go. You could accumulate that value manually, or you could use `defaultdict` to do the accumulation. Then you can break out your totals by the required arguments after having done the counting.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_e(source, ignore_accents=False, ignore_case=False):

    counts = Counter(source)
    results = {}

    lower_case_e = 'e'
    upper_case_E = 'E'
    accent_lower_case = ['é', 'ê', 'è']
    accent_upper_case = ['É', 'Ê', 'È']
    all_letters_e = [lower_case_e, upper_case_E] + accent_upper_case + accent_lower_case

    lower_e_count = counts[lower_case_e]
    upper_E_count = counts[upper_case_E]

    if ignore_case and ignore_accents:
        total = sum(counts[x] for x in all_letters_e)
        key = 'Total number of E-shaped letters in sentence ignoring case and accents'
        results[key] = total
    elif ignore_case:
        key = 'Total number of letter {} in sentence ignoring case'
        results[key.format('E')] = upper_E_count + lower_e_count

        for uc, lc in zip(accent_upper_case, accent_lower_case):
            results[key.format(uc)] = counts[uc] + counts[lc]
    elif ignore_accents:
        key = 'Total number of {} case letter {} in sentence ignoring accents'

        lower_accent_total = sum(counts[x] for x in accent_lower_case)
        results[key.format('lower', lower_case_e)] = lower_e_count + lower_accent_total

        upper_accent_total = sum(counts[y] for y in accent_upper_case)
        results[key.format('upper', upper_case_E)] = upper_E_count + upper_accent_total
    else:
        key = 'Total number of letter {} in sentence'
        for letter in all_letters_e:
            results[key.format(letter)] = counts[letter]
    return results
```